# How to match php variable but not inside single quoted string

Tags: php, regex

I need to match php variable but not method call, not inside single quote and not if $ is escaped.

is should match:

```
$foo
"$bar"
```

but not when used like this:

```
$foo->bar
'foo $bar baz'
"\$foo"
```

So far I have this regex: `"/(?<!\\\\)\$(\w*+(?!->))/"` that don't match method call and escaped dolar [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gY5dR5/1)

Comment: Need to parse php? A big ask for regex. You'd have to exclude quotes/comments, and anything else that can hide stuff. I don't see how a $ could be escaped outside a quote/comment, do you?

Comment: Also, the check that something is _not escaped `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*something`_ and something that _is escaped `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\something`_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in PCRE with verbs `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)`:

```
'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!\\)\$([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\b(?!->)
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*' # will match text between single quotes skipping escaped quotes
(*SKIP)(*F)              # skips above single quoted text
(?<!\\)                  # negative lookbehind to fail the match is $ is preceded by \
[a-zA-Z_]\w*             # will match a variable starting with $, \b is for word boundary
(?!->)                   # negative lookahead to fail the match if -> is at next position
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gY5dR5/4)

Comment: How about escaped quotes `'$foo \'$bar\' '`?

Comment: But he said not between single quotes. Didn't he? I think it will go to get more and more complex.

Comment: Good. But we don't have such variables `$999` either. It should be considered as a dollar signed amount and get ignored.